# Split Slick Slideshow add Autoplay

Tags: css, html, slideshow

I found a slider I liked at: https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE

The only thing I'd like to add is an `autoplay` feature. The good thing is it uses Slick slideshow, which has an `autoplay` feature, so I thought this was going to be easy. I added the `autoplay` argument, which worked, but some of the transitions match up to the wrong pictures...I'm pretty sure it's because of the fancy transitions, but I'm not sure what to change. Can anyone help me get this going?

My code is below, it's the original code with the `autoplay` argument:

```
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
dragging = false,
tracking,
rightTracking;

sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
    $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');

$('.slideshow-left').slick({
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 1000,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
        $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
        $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    } else {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
        $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
    }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
    } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
    dragging = true;
    tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
    tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
    rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
    rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
    if (dragging) {
        newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
        newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
        diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
        $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
    }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
    dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
    swipe: false,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 950,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
    initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});

$('.slideshow-text').slick({
    swipe: false,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 900,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

The new Codepen: https://codepen.io/joshrodgers/pen/mdyGoaB

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: you want auto play?

Comment: @sarvesh Dineshkumar Patel - I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! My initial suspicions were correct, I needed to add the `autoplay` argument to the slideshow, but only the left slideshow. All of the others did not need it and everything is working properly!

```
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
dragging = false,
tracking,
rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
    $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
        $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
        $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    } else {
        $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
    }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
    } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
    dragging = true;
    tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
    tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
    rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
    rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
    if (dragging) {
        newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
        newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
        diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
        $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
    }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
    dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
    swipe: false,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 950,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
    initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});

$('.slideshow-text').slick({
    swipe: false,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 900,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

Final Codepen: https://codepen.io/joshrodgers/pen/RwNeaNv

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that by adding 'autoplay', both sliders run in the same direction. You can probably autoplay one of them in reverse:

```
$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
    swipe: false,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 950,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
    initialSlide: maxItems - 1,
    rtl: true,
});
```

Comment: I tried this...it does match the images properly, but then the transitions misbehave :-( I did find a solution though! Thanks for trying.